# Using Excel VBA, how do I calculate a sum based on other conditions in that row?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, sum, vba

I'd like help with a macro to look at columns A and C in the current row and then search the sheet I'm on for matches to both columns A and C. If the row matches both columns, the macro would then add column E. I then want the sum to output in column F.

- Look columns A and C of current row
- Find all rows with matching columns A *and* C
- For all rows that had a match, sum up their cells in column E and display them in all of their column F's

I was thinking that I would create a string to compare A and C, but I don't know how to do a sum if the conditions are met.

Here's the idea I started with:

```
strCriteria = Cells(.Row, "A"), Cells(.Row, "C").Value
Do While Cells(.Row, "A"), Cells(.Row, "C").Value = strCriteria
```

Any pointers or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does it need to be a macro? `=SUMIF` should work fine, otherwise.

Comment: What is `Cells(.Row, "A"), Cells(.Row, "C").Value` supposed to be?  `Cells` will be against the active worksheet.  `.Row` will be against a With statement.  At the moment it is a list and you cannot set strCriteria to a list.  Are you trying to specify a range or do you want to concatenate the two cells?  For concatenation you want: `Cells(.Row, "A").Value & Cells(.Row, "C").Value`.  What do you want to sum for column "F"?

Comment: I'm trying to specify a range. I'd like to search the sheet for matches of both columns A and C, and allow other users to do the same search if they add more data later.

Comment: This should be totally doable with normal formulas - let me know if you will have any troubles, I should be able to help

Comment: I didn't understand completely but you should try the `SUMIFS` function. It allows you to specify several criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try a worksheet formula:

in cell **E3** put this formula:

`=IF(A:A=C:C,SUM(A3:C3),0)`

then copy down.

in VBA you could do something similar.